# webdriver :: contextClick(webElement) not opening the context menu

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to open the context menu for my automated test using selenium 2. The things I have tried are:-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
//location is = "largeImageF-img"
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id(location));
actions.contextClick(webElement);
```

Its not opening the context menu.

I tried using

```
selenium.contextMenu(xpath);
//selenium was instantiated using WebDriverBackedSelenium
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `Action` class implements the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Thus you can chain several calls to create one sequence of actions. To execute them, you must invoke `perform()` in the end:

```
actions.contextClick(webElement).perform();
```

Your code does not execute the action.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your reply. I do get your point that I need to use perform(). But not sure why action is not being exceuted. The steps I used are

 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("http://....");
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id(location));
actions.contextClick(webElement).method();

  Am I missing something. Thanks,

Comment: @user978301: Sorry, your comment does not make sense. There is no method Actions.method(). Also, please edit your question if you need to amend/correct it. That way everyone sees your correction.

Comment: @user978301: It should be actions.contextClick(webElement).perform() instead of actions.contextClick(webElement).method()

Answer (score 0):

I did not check WebDriverBackedSelenium but I am sure it **works for Firefox and MSIE starting version 2.8**, check your version.  As for changes in past Seleinum 2 releases, you can get more information on [Selenium blog](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/10/remarkable-changes-in-past-versions.html). Or look at this "extract" : http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/10/remarkable-changes-in-past-versions.html - there are slo examples how to use it correctly, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue, and it turns out that in my case this was a bug in Selenium where contextClick would not work properly inside an iFrame.  For more details: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2950.  This bug was just fixed.